# Why do people say “see you in the next video” in a video even thought I am the one who is going to see them?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I see this in many YouTube videos where the person says something like “and I’ll see you in the next one,” but I never understood what that actually means. To me, it sounds like it should be something like “and I hope you see my next video” or “and I hope you see me in my next video.”

Can someone please explain to me this form of sentence, what it actually means, and why it is used in that way?

Comment: At a guess, it's to give the impression that your video watching is more interactive than it actually is. There's probably some psychology (beyond the scope of this SE) behind the wording which is intended to make you more likely to 'come back' for the next video. Ultimately only the speaker can truely answer _why_ they said it.

Comment: It makes it seem more like someone giving lessons in a classroom, where the next lesson will happen whether or not you attend. It's just being friendly.

Comment: I don't know about elsewhere, but in the UK, it is quite common for presenters of a regular TV programme to say e.g. 'see you tomorrow, next week', etc. There is a pretence that we are physically meeting them. Of course we know that they can't really see us, and in any case, 'see' can mean 'encounter or meet'. I know a blind person who uses 'see' this way.